# Can not get AEC model Data in Autodesk Forge

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, forge

i try to activate Revit Levels and 2D Minimap extension in autodesk forge viewer, but can not get AEC Model Data. I got this worning`

[image]

i tried to get AEC data with this code

```
const url = window.location.search;
console.log(url);
const svf_path = `${url.replace("?", "/storage/").replace(/%20/g, " ")}`;

Autodesk.Viewing.endpoint.getItemApi = (endpoint, derivativeUrn, api) => {
  return svf_path;
};

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, async () => {
  const paths = svf_path.split("/");
  const [dest, svf_dir] = [paths[2], paths[3]];

  const url = `/api/viewer/dest/${dest}/svf/${svf_dir}/manifest`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const manifest = await response.json();

  const init_div = document.getElementById("init_div");
  viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(init_div, config3d);

  const viewerDocument = new Autodesk.Viewing.Document(manifest);
  const viewable = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
  viewer.start();

  await viewerDocument.downloadAecModelData();

  viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, viewable)
  .then(function (result) {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(viewable);
  })
});
```

wats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The warning comes from the `BubbleNode.prototype.getAecModelData` method. You are not calling it in your code but it's possible that it's being called by the `LevelsExtension` itself. Try configuring the extension so that it doesn't detect the AEC data automatically by passing in `{ autoDetectAecModelData: false }` as the extension options.

Btw. to debug the issue on your side, you can also try getting the non-minified version of *viewer3D.js*, put a breakpoint to where the warning is being logged, and see the call stack when the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: where do i need to add autoDetectAecModelData: false ??

Comment: When you need to load an extension with custom settings, you can do it like so: `viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension', { autoDetectAecModelData: false });`